# Missing semicolon

Tags: javascript

### Solved

In the below code Firefox says I am missing `;` before the statement on line 3. How can I fix this?

This is to load some [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded content from a text file and use it elsewhere in the program.

```
function preloader(url,handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success:function(data) {
            handleData(data);
        }
    });
}
preloader("extra/joke_img.txt",function(output){var localStorage['joke_img']=output;});
```

Comment: Is that your whole script? I get no error on the 3rd line.

Comment: It is because of the use of var in your preloader function. You need to either set localStorate property or create a new var.

Comment: hmm that is the line that Firefox is mad at

Comment: Are you trying to create a variable called localStoarge there? Or are you trying to set some value in an already existing variable ?

Comment: @user1495129 - Like @ryadavilli says, remove `var` from the front of `localStorage` if it's already defined.